# How to get product title within selectCallback function?

Tags: shopify

I need to add different suffixes to prices based on different products, e.g. 'per case', 'per pair' etc. The only way I can think of to do this is to check the product's name (thankfully only three products are different than others). I found that the suffix was created by this `selectCallback` function. But the function `var selectCallback = function(variant, selector)` seems to be limited to variant control only. How can I get the product title in that function? And if anyone has a better idea to add different suffixes to prices, I'm all ears. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

you can get all product data from liquid object to javascript(in product page):

```
<script>
  var product = {{ product | json }};
  console.log(product);
</script>
```

the selectCallback function, you can modify to your convenience:

```
selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
    ...
    ...
    console.log(variant);
    if (variant) {
      ...
      ...
    }
    if (variant && variant.available == true) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  };
```